# Use has_filter on comment_post

Tags: filters, comments, hooks, actions, comment-meta

I hook to comment form (on comment_form_logged_in_after if user is logged in and comment_form_before_fields if not) to add 2 fields (rating and title).

These fields can be mandatory or comment will not save.
These fields will not appear on comment reply or if review are not enabled for a certain post or page.

If these fields are mandatory, I've to check on comment_post (just before to save comment) if filter has run, and if not just save the comment withoud any comment_meta.

The problem is that if I try to use

```
has_filter('comment_form_before_fields', 'my_function_to_check');
```

when I hook on comment_post it ALWAYS return FALSE.

If, for example, I try to show

```
var_dump(has_filter('comment_form_before_fields', 'my_function_to_check'))
```

on comment_text filter it works.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is the filter `my_function_to_check` on `comment_form_before_fields` added? Could you post all relevant code — especially where the filter is added and when the function that adds the filter is called.

Comment: thank's for the answer, this is an example:

    add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'add_input_to_comment_form' );

this add_action is inside a function hooked on **comment_form_before**

Comment: Adding an action can be done at any point, basically, after WordPress is initiated. Could you try adding it on action `init` instead of on `comment_form_before`?

Comment: Good :-). I'll add an answer to the question so it can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the action on `comment_form_before_fields` in `comment_form_logged_in_after`. The latter is called only when the user is logged in, and the former is only called when the user is *not* logged in.

You can add WordPress actions and filters at any time after WordPress is initialized. If you're adding the action in a plugin, add it on `init` or even when the code is first executed (i.e. not on an action but directly in the plugin).

This way, the action is added immediately and called when it needs to be called.